In ClickUp, How to set visibility of specific custom fields in a task type
I have two text custom fields "Field A" and "Field B". I have two Custom Task Types "Task Type A" and "Task Type B". I want to show Field A in Task Type A and Field B in Task Type B only. Not both of the fields in all task types. How can I do this. Please help.
I tried, but both fields are showing in both Task Types. Both fields are not pinned or required and they have no data.
